# Can you implement 3 interfaces and extend as well, java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Write the first line of the definition for a Stereo class. The class should extend the SoundSystem class, and it should implement the CDplayable, TunerPlayable, and CassettePlayable interfaces.

```
public class Stereo extends SoundSystem implements CDplayable, TunerPlayable, CassettePlayable{
```

is this correct??

Comment: Yes, it should work. You can test using a compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A class can implement any number of interfaces but can extend only one class..

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. But in case of interface, yes then can be achieved.

One more thing to note here is, you cannot `extend` a final class, and you have to extend an `abstract` class, if you want to instantiate it. But otherwise, you can always use `Static`  members of `abstract class` through `class name`.

See [JLS - Subclassing and Subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) and [JLS - Superinterfaces and Subinterfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3) for more details on this context.

Comment: You don't have to extend an abstract class.

Comment: You do if you want to actually instantiate and use it (apart from static methods of course).

Comment: @DNA. Yeah, actually I'll add it explicitly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically that is correct. You can implement multiple interfaces and extend only one class.

Whether your code compiles fine are not depends on access level of `SoundSystem` class.